# Downloads timing out after 30 seconds on users with slow connections

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, gunicorn, nginx-ingress, filesaver.js

We have some files on our portal that aren't that big to me: 50MB-80MB. On my home connection, it takes <10seconds to download these files. I've had other users test and they experience the same thing.

However, in the office, the connection is terrible. These files don't even download because once the download time gets to about 30-35 seconds, even though it is downloading (just incredibly slow), it triggers a non-descriptive error in the Developer Tools > Network and stops the download. Not seeing anything in any logs that indicates why the download is terminated.

The bigger problem is we now have a few end users with crappy internet who are also experiencing the same issue.

So I'm trying to figure out what we can do on our end. Obviously, we can't tell them, "Well, just get better internet service." It seems like there can be something done on our end to persist the download until it is completed. What that is, I'm not quite sure and that is what I'm looking for help on. Maybe it is a default setting in a dependency somewhere in our stack.

- ReactJS FE that uses [`FileSaver.js`](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) for downloads
- Django BE using native Django downloading
- `nginx-ingress` for traffic ingress controller to the Kubernetes cluster
- The FE uses `nginx` to serve the FE
- The BE uses `gunicorn` to serve the BE

Any suggestions on what I should do to prevent this timeout on downloads?

I'm thinking the issue is somewhere with `nginx-ingress`, `nginx`, and/or `FileSaver.js`, so investigating those.

Comment: This is how I would debug: (1) Check gunicorn logs, gunicorn timeout and what worker type are you using? Are you seeing any workers being timed-out in gunicorn logs? The default Gunicorn `timeout is 30` and most likely the cause of error.

(2) If no error in Step 1. and request is being processed well under the request timeout, then I'll go and check the nginx timeout configuration

Look at the design considerations of Gunicorn: [timeout](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#timeout) and [Worker Type](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#timeout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Saurabh, adjusting the [`timeout`](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#timeout) did the trick. I now just start the web server with the `-t 300` flag and the users that were having issues no longer do.